# How does running a program from command line work, e.g. ipython?

Tags: command-line

This is a naive command line question. After I installed anaconda I could just type "ipython" and the interpreter would appear in the terminal window. What are the mechanics behind this, i.e. how and why does it work? Is there a reference explaining this somewhere?

Comment: See this link. You're looking for information on the $PATH environment variable. http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: This going to get closed as too broad. Google about Bash for starters then buy the book Unix in a Nutshell and that should explain a lot more than you thought you'd wanna know and it's a great reference. It's easy to understand but not simple.